# Forum email url & login redirect

Tags: forum

I have a site that is using the forum module. Although the forum is password protected itself, members must be logged in to the website using a custom template before they can access the forum.

When someone tries to access a forum URL, they are redirected to the custom template to log in. I did this by putting a PHP redirect in the forum header template.

The problem is when a member is subscribed to a forum thread and gets a notification email from the forum with a URL to a forum post in it, the link takes them to the forum post page but redirects them to the custom login page.

When the member logs in, the chain is broken and they do not get redirected to the forum post.

Os there a way to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured out the problem. It was a return parameter setting that was sending logged in users to the same page no matter where they came from.